# Extraer parámetro de archivo usando bash

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Necesito un programa en bash que a partir de un fichero de texto de decenas de líneas, entre las cuales se encuentra esta línea:

```
</script><h4 id="active">Active Batches (0)
```

me permita obtener el valor entre paréntesis después de la cadena `"Active Batches"` en formato número.

Con un `grep` podría encontrar la línea donde se encuentra `"Active Batches"` y extraerla del texto pero luego no se como obtener el valor entre paréntesis.

Comment: sería bueno que mostraras qué has intentado pero, sobre todo, qué otras líneas hay. Las respuestas que hay podrían "romperse" si hay líneas muy parecidas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar esta expresión regular con `grep`:

```
"(?(?<=Active Batches \()\d|)"
```

El comando, como lo probé es:

```
$ echo "</script><h4 id="active">Active Batches (0)" | grep -Po "(?(?<=Active Batches \()\d|)"
0
```

Y con tu archivo:

```
$ grep -Po "(?(?<=Active Batches \()\d|)" mi_archivo.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sería utilizar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
(?<=Active Batches\s\()\d+(?=\))
```

Que busca cualquier número que exista al menos una vez ("\d+") y que se encuentre dentro de las cadenas "Active Batches (" y ")" (para eso están "(?<=)" y "(?=)" ).

La forma de usar esa expresión con `grep` es habilitando las expresiones tipo *PERL* o obteniendo únicamente lo capturado en la expresión regular, pare eso se usan los parámetros `-Po`.

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Active Batches\s\()\d+(?=\))' <(echo '</script><h4 id="active">Active Batches (0)
</script><h4 id="active">Active Batches (5)
</script><h4 id="active">Active Batches (ttt)
</script><h4 id="active">Active Batches ()
</script><h4 id="active">Active Batches (77)')
0  
5  
77
```

Para poder probarlo con un archivo "normal", sólo cambia el process substitution por un nombre de archivo.

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=Active Batches\s\()\d+(?=\))' archivo.txt
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funcíonó. ¿Y si quisiera hacerlo en el prompt de windows como sería?

Comment: Si te funcionó, me harías un gran favor poniéndola como la respuesta adecuada (a menos que otra te haya funcionado mejor), y/o puntuar de forma positiva.
En el caso de windows (powershell) deberías hacer otra pregunta preguntando por ese programa en específico, o modificar tu pregunta y añadiéndole la etiuqueta de `powershell`